# How should I use make to allow me to run all python scripts in a directory?

Tags: python, makefile, python-venv

I'm using the excellent Makefile.venv

https://github.com/sio/Makefile.venv

to handle various aspects of python virtual environments.

To run my hello world program, I have a target:

```
hello: venv
    $(VENV)/python hello.py
```

Notice that it depends on `venv` (which target sets up the virtual environment correctly), but not on `hello.py`, since that's just the script I wish to run when I type 'make hello', and I want this to happen whether or not the file's been updated recently.

This works perfectly, but I've started to accumulate rules like this, eg:

```
hello-pyparsing: venv
    $(VENV)/python hello-pyparsing.py

generators: venv
    $(VENV)/python generators.py
```

How should I abstract the common pattern to say that any `.py` file in the directory is a possible target?

Bonus points if bash command completion works, ie `make <Tab>` gives me a list like `hello, hello-pyparsing, generators` to choose from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
ALLPYS := $(patsubst %.py,%,$(wildcard *.py))

$(ALLPYS): venv
        $(VENV)/python $@.py

.PHONY: $(ALLPYS)
```

I don't know much about bash command completion for makefiles but I assume the above will work with it.

Comment: lovely, thanks! don't get bash completions but that's a different question.

Comment: I would have assumed that bash completions would use the output of `make -p` but maybe it tries to parse the makefile directly.  If the latter then it wouldn't work with this.

Comment: So, er, this wasn't working yesterday (I checked!!) but it has started working today. No idea why....